# C++ core dump error while implementing family tree

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, coredump

I'm trying to implement family tree. I have the classes `Person` and `Tree` defined as follows:

**File `FamilyTree.hpp`:**

```
using namespace std;
#include <string>

namespace family{

    class Person{
        public:
        string name;
        Person* mother;
        Person* father;

        Person(string name);

    };

    class Tree{
        public:
        Person* root;

        Tree(string name);

        Tree& addFather(string name1, string name2);
        Tree addMother(string name1, string name2);
        void display();
        string relation(string name);
        string find(string name);
        void remove(string name);
    };

};
```

**File `FamilyTree.cpp`:**

```
#include "FamilyTree.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace family;   

// FUNCTIONS

Person& findPerson(Person& root, string child_name){
    if (root.name.compare(child_name) != 0)
    {
        cout<<root.name<<":1"<<endl;
        findPerson(*root.father, child_name);
    }
    else if(root.name.compare(child_name) == 0){
        cout<<root.name<<":2"<<endl;
        return root;  
    }else{
        cout<<"not found!!!"<<endl;
        Person p("no found");
        return p;
    }
}

// PERSON
family::Person::Person(string person_name){
    name = person_name;
    father = nullptr;
    mother = nullptr;
};

// TREE
family::Tree::Tree(string name){
    root = new Person(name);
};

family::Tree& Tree::addFather(string child, string father){
    Person& child_found = findPerson(*root, child);

    //cout<<"child_found.name:"<<child_found.name<<endl;
    child_found.father = new Person(father);
    return *this;
    };

family::Tree family::Tree::addMother(string name1, string name2){return Tree("");};
void family::Tree::display(){};
string family::Tree::relation(string name){return "";};
string family::Tree::find(string name){return "";};
void family::Tree::remove(string name){};

int main(){
    Tree t("X");

    t.addFather("X", "Y");
    t.addFather("Y","Z");
    return 0;
}
```

I started with `addFather()` function: 
`addFather("child", "new father")` for adding new father for existing child.
I implemented it recursively using `findPerson()` function, which  returns the `Person` object for the child and `addFather()` func creating new `Person` and initializing it to found child.

After I add 2 fathers, I get Illegal instruction (core dumped) error, what should be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turn on your warnings, you'll see that you're not always returning from `findPerson`. In this function

```
Person& findPerson(Person& root, string child_name){
    if (root.name.compare(child_name) != 0)
    {
        cout<<root.name<<":1"<<endl;
        findPerson(*root.father, child_name);      // (1)
    }
    else if(root.name.compare(child_name) == 0){
        cout<<root.name<<":2"<<endl;
        return root;  
    }else{
        cout<<"not found!!!"<<endl;
        Person p("no found");
        return p;                      // (2)
    }
}
```

The code in the first `if`-branch, marked `(1)`, needs to return the recursively-found Person, like this

```
return findPerson(*root.father, child_name);
```

That should take care of the segfault.

However, there is a deeper issue in the last branch of this function, where you are returning a reference to a local variable `p`, marked `(2)`. If you do this, you are returning a dangling reference, since `p` will go out of scope when the function returns.

You need to think about what this function should do if no Person is found.

- You could maybe return a `Person*`, so `nullptr` means no Person is found.
- You could return an `std::optional<Person>`.

Comment: This is a very comprehensive answer. I immediately spotted on the return of a reference to a local, but in my answer I didn‘t take notice the missing return. Well done +1

Comment: Works perfectly now, but my question now is: why I should return the function? the IF state should return nothing. because my ELSE IF state responsible for this.

Comment: It's a rule of c++ that if a function says it will return something, it MUST return something. Apart from that, it looks like the logic of the function requires a recursive return. That's not necessary as far as the compiler is concerned, but returning *something* is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot return a reference to a local object.  THis will result in undefined behavior.

When you add a new member, the `findPerson()` will not find it an try to return such a local object p. This is doomed to fail.

This design is not optimal. Possible solutions:

- declare a static object p that is returned when nothing is found. Unlike locals, static remain alive and the reference returned would then stay valid.  You have to make sure however that this the returned reference is never used in a way that may change the name of your static object.
- change the interface of `findPerson()` so that it return pointers.  Either it returns a valid pointer to a person, or it returns `nullptr` if nothing is found.  This is a common idiom (in real world development, you would return an iterator but if you're beginning in C++, this would be too complex for the time being).
- throw an exception if nothing is found and rewrite your calling code so that it catches the exception.  I would not advise to use this approach here:  exceptions are better kept for really exceptional situations.

Note that I did not look in your code if there were other errors.  I just stoped at the first attempt to find something that doesn't exist when the tree is empty.

Answer (score 0):

It working for fathers search, but I need it to iterate over all of the tree.
When I added mothers root it core dumping again.

```
Person& findPerson(Person& root, string child_name){
    if (root.name.compare(child_name) != 0)
    {
        //cout<<root.name<<":1"<<endl;
        return findPerson(*root.father, child_name); 
        return findPerson(*root.mother, child_name);     // (1)
    }
    else if(root.name.compare(child_name) == 0){
        //cout<<root.name<<":2"<<endl;
        return root;  
    }else{
        throw exception();                     
    }
}
```

Comment: Any solution for this one?